# Can I reuse the prepared statement object

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

In many occasions I'm using more than 1 prepared statements, like so

```
$conn = connect('read'); // connect to the database

$q = 'SELECT ...';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($a, $b, $c);
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();


$q = 'SELECT ...';
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare($q);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->store_result();
$stmt2->bind_result($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f...);
$stmt2->free_result();
$stmt2->close();


$conn->close(); // close db connection
```

And sometimes it's just a mess trying to figure out what number to give to the **stmt** variable...

Can I reuse the **stmt** object over and over once I close it using `stmt->close()` That way I don't need to keep trace of what index to give to the variable stmt?

Is this good practice or bad practice?

Comment: If they are different queries you will need different stmt objects.
If it's the same query, you can reuse the object.

Comment: If you prepare a query, you should be able to bind params multiple times and reuse it, I believe.

Comment: you can. it is perfectly valid to reassign another prepared statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to reuse a variable is all right and even quite good a practice.

Aside from that, don't you think it's quite repetitive to use all this code again and again? What about using a *function*, to make things like

```
$row = function('SELECT ...', $params);
list($a, $b, $c) = function('SELECT ...', $another);
```

Comment: i like the idea of creating a function, i just need to learn how to pass multiple parameters with the variable type and return them correctly.. any links of tutorials? thanks

Comment: no tutorials required actually. always pass 2 parameters - a query and an array with data to bind. and return an array with data

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be a good idea but as far as you have control over the executiong of your code blocks, what happens if the stmt->close() never reaches because of some error and you start a new set. if you can take care of this and these kind of situations it will be a good idea.